# ElasticSearch avoid 100% of JVM Heap

Tags: elasticsearch, garbage-collection, jvm

How to avoid 100% of JVM heap in ElasticSearch and that the garbage collector cleaups the heap?

In my case, when the JVM heap is coming to 99% the site don't respond anymore. Some tips?

Here a screen from Marvel.[image]

elasticsearch.yml config

cluster.name: xxx

```
node.name: xxxx
node.data: true
node.master: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
transport.tcp.compress: true;
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.max_content_length: 500mb

index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 10s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 5s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 2s
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 500ms

script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
index.max_result_window: 10000
```

And a heap size of 24g on 9G index.

EDIT -- GC LOG

```
: 553545K->8330K(613440K), 0.0557428 secs] 732889K->188315K(25097728K), 0.0558526 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
2017-06-05T10:55:25.416+0200: 88.445: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0561829 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000684 seconds
2017-06-05T10:55:26.416+0200: 89.446: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002122 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000832 seconds
2017-06-05T10:55:26.833+0200: 89.863: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-06-05T10:55:26.834+0200: 89.863: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 34865152 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:     530096 bytes,     530096 total
- age   2:     920856 bytes,    1450952 total
- age   3:    1311064 bytes,    2762016 total
- age   4:     258584 bytes,    3020600 total
- age   5:     600504 bytes,    3621104 total
- age   6:     717384 bytes,    4338488 total
: 553674K->5918K(613440K), 0.0450758 secs] 733659K->186089K(25097728K), 0.0451704 secs] [Times: user=0.35 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
```

Comment: can you show es logs?

Comment: Please share the gc logs, we will be able to recommend fine tuning vm arguments (Use -XX:+PrintGC to get the GC logs)

Comment: Is this a log you want to have? I have enabled it and now my java process has this additional options: JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintClassHistogram"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xloggc:$ES_GC_LOG_FILE"